# Creating custom elements doesn't work - createElement()

Tags: javascript, html, createelement

I'm trying to keep my project readable for myself, and I'm trying to create new custom HTML elements.

```js
document.createElement("name", {is: "h2"});
document.createElement("avatar", {is: "img"});
document.createElement("description", {is: "p"});
```

This is how I use them

```js
$(`<avatar class="dropshadow" src="${friend.avatar}">`).appendTo(box);
$(`<name class="name">${friend.name}</name>`).appendTo(box);
$(`<description class="noselect">${friend.description}</description>`).appendTo(box);
```

Unfortunately, none of these work. They are not treated as their inherited element.
When inspecting the nodes, the prototypes are `HTMLUnknownElementPrototype`, which tells me it doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong here? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't think that's they way it works. Check out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)!

Comment: I've looked at the documentation multiple times, everything I try does not work. I cannot create my own elements with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well boy aren't I dumb
custom elements cannot be created with `createElement()`, but with `customElements.define()`, with the limitation being that the tag name must include a hyphen.

[Look here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define)

Comment: I would have done it right then and there but stackoverflow said I could accept an answer in 23 hours, and I still cant accept it as an answer for 13 hours

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `createElement` is the tag name.

```
const name = document.createElement('h2');
const avatar = document.createElement('img');
const description = document.createElement('p');
```

Comment: setting the variable name doesn't reflect its tag name in the DOM. It wouldn't show up as `<avatar>`, it would just be `<img>`